# Matrix bracket font on system?

Tags: fonts, amsmath, matrices, brackets, illustrator

When I "place" a page of a LaTeX document into Adobe Illustrator CS6 *without* "linking" the original file, it attempts to use system fonts (not embedded fonts). As long as I have all the fonts loaded on my system, most everything looks fine, except some `bmatrix` (and occasionally other large) brackets.

Illustrator replaces them with the x-boxes or other strange characters, shown below. Interestingly, Illustrator doesn't complain about not having the font, which it's usually good about doing.

I wonder if LaTeX's using some special bracket font my system doesn't have?

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[small,euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\ 0 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output file in a pdf viewer.

[image: pdf looks fine]

And here it is in Illustrator.

[image: in illustrator]

Comment: @RicoPicone, your code snippet is not compilable. we need complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...} and ending with`\end{document}` .

Comment: @Zarko, I have now included a MWE.

Comment: For what it's worth, this issue persists when loading only the `amsmath` package. Also, every once in a while (apparently not deterministically!), when "place"ing the file, Illustrator will complain it does not have font "SFRM1000" ... which I understand to be a Computer Modern font. I've tried installing all CM fonts I can find on my macOS, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

After thrashing about with fonts for a long time, I decided to avoid the entire question of fonts by *outlining* them before "place"ing them in Illustrator.
This has the advantage of solving the issue for all fonts, but doesn't allow text editing, per se—not a problem for me.

An automatic way of doing this with Ghostscript is as follows.

```
gs -o file_outlined.pdf \ 
  -dNoOutputFonts \
  -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
  -dEncodeColorImages=false \
  -dEncodeGrayImages=false \
  -dEncodeMonoImages=false \ 
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  file.pdf
```

The outlining is given by the `-dNoOutputFonts` flag. The other flags aren't necessary, but (as I understand) avoid re-encoding images in the file.

I realize this is more of a workaround solution, so I will happily entertain more legitimate solutions.